# Write a select query for getting table value using another table field value

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having two tables student and guardian table

So I want to write a query to get the guardian name guardian age from guardian using stu_uid retrievd from student table using stu_id which will be static

```
Select guardian_nm,guardian_age 
from guardian 
where stu_uid=(select stu_uid from student where stu_id=1)
```

I wrote a query like above but not working

Can anyone pls help me

Thanks in advance

Comment: "Not working" is vague. What is the error? Wrong result may be?

Comment: If stu_uid is not static and you want get more rows as per stu_uid then use below query

`Select guardian_nm,guardian_age 
from guardian 
where stu_uid IN (select stu_uid from student)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead, write your query as below

```
Select `guardian_nm`, `guardian_age` from `guardian` where `stu_uid` = 1;
```

Since your student id is static use it directly on the query instead of writing subqueries

or else you can use inner joins, to learn more about inner queries follow the link below

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

Try this for inner join,

```
SELECT `guardian`.`guardian_nm`, `guardian`.`guardian_age`, `guardian`.`stu_uid` 
FROM `guardian`
INNER JOIN `student` ON `guardian`.`stu_uid` = `student`.`stu_id`
WHERE `student`.`stu_id` = '1';
```

Comment: Sr I just changes one is stu_uid and other is stu_id

Comment: SELECT guardian.guardian_nm, guardian.guardian_age, guardian.stu_uid
FROM guardian
INNER JOIN student
ON guardian.stu_uid= student.stu_id;

Try this

Comment: my table will be like stu.student like that I will call so can I call stu.student.stu_id

Comment: If `stu.student` is the name of your table then you can. something like `\`stu.student\`.\`stu_id\``

Comment: Worked thanks If I want to take the stu id and latest timestamp means can you pls help me

Comment: @coder Sure just be clear about the required output.
If you want to add `stu_id` and `timestamp` in the result you are getting out of query then just request these two columns in the `SELECT statement` of your query

Comment: No I want to get the stu_id which is having latest timestamp

Comment: Can I use where student.stu_id =1 AND student.timestamp= how to get latest timestamp

Comment: i tried where student.stu_id =1 AND student.timestamp= max(timestamp) // not working @groovy_guy pls help me

Comment: try to use `ORDER BY \`student\`.\`timestamp\` DESC` instead

Comment: I need to get only one latest record not all

Comment: `ORDER BY \`student\`.\`timestamp\` DESC LIMIT 1`

Comment: Select guardian_nm,guardian_age from guardian where stu_uid IN (select stu_uid from student where stu_id=1 order by timestamp desc limit 1 )

Comment: `SELECT \`guardian\`.\`guardian_nm\`, \`guardian\`.\`guardian_age\`,
\`guardian\`.\`stu_uid\` 
FROM \`guardian\` 
INNER JOIN \`student\` ON \`guardian\`.\`stu_uid\` = \`student\`.\`stu_id\` 
WHERE \`student\`.\`stu_id\` = '1'
ORDER BY \`student\`.\`timestamp\` DESC LIMIT 1`

Try this again

Comment: Without join what is wrong in my query can you pls say?

Comment: sure copy-paste here the error you are getting when you try to execute your query

Comment: Error code is -4743 ATTEMPT TO USE A FUNCTION WHEN THE APPLICATION COMPATIBILITY SETTING IS SET FOR A PREVIOUS LEVEL

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236848/discussion-between-coder-and-groovy-guy).

Answer (score 1):

Use join in your query, you have not provided the table structure, so I have to guess, your query may be like this or similar to this depending on the table structure.

```
SELECT `a`.`guardian_nm`, `a`.`guardian_age` 
FROM `guardian` `a` 
INNER JOIN `student` `b` 
ON `a`.`stu_uid` = `b`.`stu_uid` 
WHERE `b`.`stu_id` = '1';
```