# Get the record from the table using the latest record field from another table

Tags: sql

From this question

[Write a select query for getting table value using another table field value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69083287/write-a-select-query-for-getting-table-value-using-another-table-field-value/69083337?noredirect=1#comment122105851_69083337)

I tried this query

```
 select guardian_nm,guardian_age 
 from guardian 
 where stu_uid IN (
 select stu_uid from student where stu_id=1 order by timestamp desc limit 1)
```

But getting the following error

> Error code is -4743 ATTEMPT TO USE A FUNCTION WHEN THE APPLICATION
> COMPATIBILITY SETTING IS SET FOR A PREVIOUS LEVEL

Can anyone help me please ?

Comment: Why are you using `IN()` when you specify `LIMIT 1`?  Just use `=`?

Comment: I ***strongly*** recommend setting up a demonstration in https://dbfiddle.uk (or similar) to both demonstrate the error, and provided an example to provide you with a suitable query for your needs.

Comment: That is not a MySQL error.  Your question is confusing.

Comment: @Gordon its an sql error

Comment: @coder . . . Your question is tagged MySQL.  The error is not MySQL.  That is confusing.  Tag with the database you are really using.

Comment: @Gordon sure i will could you pls help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using limit 1 so `stu_uid` you can write it  `=`.
And I will suggest do not use reserved `MYSQL` words in column names like `timestamp`,
Use join instead of subquery.

> The advantage of a join includes that it executes faster. The
> retrieval time of the query using joins almost always will be faster
> than that of a subquery. By using joins, you can maximize the
> calculation burden on the database i.e., instead of multiple queries
> using one join query.

Try:

```
select guardian_nm,guardian_age, 
from guardian  
inner join 
student 
on guardian.stu_uid=student.stu_uid 
where student.stu_id=1 
order by timestamp desc limit 1 ;
```

Working demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/923c30/3

Comment: Hi thanks for answering but i need to get guradian name and age from guardian tbl using stu_uid from student table where stu_id in student tbl

Comment: but in your on statement u took guardian.stu_uid = student.stu_id( student.stu_uid should come ) can you pls help

Comment: My req is to pull the guardian name using stu_uid which needs to come from student tbl where stu_id(this one i am giving manually) but will your query work for my case

Comment: In student tbl having stu_uids for stu_id=1 so want to pull stu_uid with latest timestamp and need query the guardian tbl with pulled stu_uid with latest timestamp @basha04

Comment: Student table - stu_id,stu_uid, timestamp-1, 111,2021-3-8-36.07.68.7909 - this is one row like this i have 112 and 113 for stu_id=1 // this is student table sample

Comment: guardian table -stu_uid,guardian_nm,guardian_age -111,ss,34 - this is one row // this is guardian table sample

Comment: So for ex first i need query the stu_uid for latest timestamp where stu_id=1 if it is 111 now want to pull guadian nm and age guardian table for stu_uid=111 pls help me @ basha04

Comment: How can you make equal on condition stu_uid= stu_id is it possible 111=1 will be coimg right?

Comment: Where is stu_uid in student table u changed table structure @basha04 i need to have that

Comment: CREATE TABLE guardian(
 stu_uid INT(9) NOT NULL ,
guardian_nm    varchar(10) NOT NULL ,
guardian_age      int(10) NOT NULL 
);

INSERT INTO  guardian VALUES (111,'test',22),(112,'test01',22),(114,'test04',25),(115,'test05',40);


CREATE TABLE student(
stu_id INT(9) NOT NULL ,
 stu_uid INT(9) NOT NULL ,
`timestamp`    timestamp 
);

INSERT INTO  student VALUES (1,111,'2021-03-04'),(1,112,'2021-03-12'),(2,114,'2021-03-21'),(1,115,'2021-12-04'),(4,116,'2021-03-04');


expected out put is: test05,40// as it has latest timestamp

Comment: Sry expected out put is: test01,22// as it has latest timestamp if i give stu_id=1 pls help